# how to load properly sql data with a new line

Tags: php, html, mysql

im trying to query my database and when im using the code below, it repeats some part of the data

```
$data = $result['testdata'];
$data = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $data);
$data = str_replace("\r", "<br>", $data);
$data = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $data);

echo "<form action='testsearch.php' method='post'>";

echo"<tr>"; 
echo  "<td align='center' width='auto'>" . $result['test'] . "<input type=hidden name=test value=" . $result['test'] . "' /> </td>";
echo  "<td align='left' width='500'>" . $data . "<input type=hidden name=testdata value=" . $data . "' /> </td>";
"</tr>";
```

here is the snapshot of the result of the code above:

[image: Code1]

now when i try to use `htmlentities` in the code to resolve the issue im losing the new line and being replace instead by `<br>`

```
$data = $result['testdata'];
$data = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $data);
$data = str_replace("\r", "<br>", $data);
$data = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $data);
$data1 = htmlentities($data);

echo "<form action='testsearch.php' method='post'>";

echo"<tr>"; 
echo  "<td align='center' width='auto'>" . $result['test'] . "<input type=hidden name=test value=" . $result['test'] . "' /> </td>";
echo  "<td align='left' width='500'>" . $data1 . "<input type=hidden name=data1 value=" . $data1 . "' /> </td>";
"</tr>";
```

here is the snapshot of the second code:

[image: Code2]

i need help in maintaining the new line and at the same time not repeating the datas fetch from mysql db...

Comment: you really should look up `nl2br()`: http://php.net/nl2br  it'll make your life a lot easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the quotes at the beginning of the `value` attributes. And you need to convert HTML special characters to entities *only* when they're inside attributes, not in the text. So it should be:

```
echo  "<td align='center' width='auto'>" . $result['test'] . "<input type=hidden name=test value='" . htmlspecialchars($result['test']) . "' /> </td>";
echo  "<td align='left' width='500'>" . $data . "<input type=hidden name=data1 value='" . htmlspecialchars($data) . "' /> </td>";
```

Comment: great...it did the trick...thanks for the help...that was so fast that i need to wait before i can accept your answer :)